# iphone - web service returns XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am very new to iPhone development, so please be gentle with me.
I have set up a web service which returns XML data. Sample data:

```
<categories>
    <category>
        <CategoryId>1</CategoryId>
        <CategoryName>cat1</CategoryName>
    </category>
    <category>
        <CategoryId>2</CategoryId>
        <CategoryName>cat2</CategoryName>
    </category>
</categories>
```

I was working on the code provided here: http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/
And I'm getting an error.
Here is the function which sets the array:

```
    -(void)parser: (NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])
    {
        [category setObject:currentID forKey:@"CategoryId"];
        [category setObject:currentName forKey:@"CategoryName"];
        [categories addObject:[currentElement copy]];
    }
}`-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"Found characters: %@", string);
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"CategoryName"])
    {
        [currentName appendString:string];
    }
    else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"CategoryId"])
    {
        [currentID appendString:string];
    }
}
```

and I get an error when I try and read from the array:

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    int categoryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
    [cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex: categoryIndex] objectForKey: @"CategoryName"];
    return cell;


}
```

I get this error:

```
2011-06-05 11:33:35.436 FirstTry[2419:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c26b40'
```

I'm a little lost with the iOS dev thing. Thank you!

Comment: This line of code does not seem right **[cell.textLabel.text** why do you have open angle bracket at the first? are you sure this code compiles?

Comment: Other thing what is the result for logging this: **NSLog("%d",[categories count]);**

Comment: I put a breakpoint there and the array has two objects, but I can't make sense of the content of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for "unrecognized selector sent to instance ..."-errors is that you are calling a function to an instance which doesn't implement that function.

You assume the following structure of your data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` `usedLocalVariableName:Class`

`categories:NSArray` which contains many `category:NSMutableDictionary` which contains the `@"CategoryName"`-Key with a `NSString` value.

Your Parse-Code results in sth different:

`categories:NSArray`which contains many `currentElement:NSString` (I assume that `currentElement` is a `NSString` because you are using `isEqualToString:`-method on `currentElement`).

So if you run that code  the code-snippet: `[categories objectAtIndex: categoryIndex]` will return a `NSString` and **not** a `NSDictionary` and `NSString` does not implement the `objectForKey:`-method.

I am not sure (I've not tested it) but I think

```
[categories addObject:[[category copy] autorelease]];
```

should work. The autorelease is against memory-leaks

Another thing: You use

```
int categoryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
```

Why not using `int categoryIndex = indexPath.row`

**edit:** You are using the NSXMLParser. I am using the [TBXML](https://web.archive.org/web/20211226132549/http://tbxml.co.uk/)-Parser which [parses faster than NSXML](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3145-xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) and is more comfortable to use.

Comment: Thank you. Noob mistake. Needed to add the dictionary to the array, not the string.